# JavaFX multithreading - joining threads won't update the UI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2, task

I am trying to make a loader dialog where the user can know that the program is loading what was requested and that the program is running as expected.

But as so, I need to `join()` the parser thread and before keep going on the main and this makes the dialog blank.

**ParserTask.java**

```
public class ParserTask extends Task<Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            //parse stuff
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            updateProgress(i,9);
            updateMessage("foo no:"+ i);
        }
        updateMessage("done");
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main  extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Progress Controls");
        Button btn = new Button("call the thread");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                threadDialog();
            }
        });
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(btn);
        scene.setRoot(vb);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    private void threadDialog() {
        Stage stageDiag = new Stage();
        ParserTask pTask = new ParserTask();
        final Label loadingLabel = new Label("");
        loadingLabel.textProperty().bind(pTask.messageProperty());
        final ProgressBar pbar = new ProgressBar();
        pbar.setProgress(0);
        pbar.setPrefHeight(20);
        pbar.setPrefWidth(450);
        pbar.progressProperty().bind(pTask.progressProperty());
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(14.0);
        grid.add(loadingLabel, 0, 0);
        grid.add(pbar, 1, 1);
        Scene sceneDiag = new Scene(grid);
        stageDiag.setScene(sceneDiag);
        stageDiag.setTitle("Foo thread is loading");
        stageDiag.show();
        Thread parser = new Thread(pTask);
        parser.start();
        try {
            parser.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If, I comment/ remove this code:

```
        try {
            parser.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, I can see the thread loading as expected, otherwise, I can only see a blank screen that will be in the final state (the last message and the full progress bar).

```
    while(!loadingLabel.getText().contains("one")){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And even `while(parser.isAlive());` without success.

My question is: How can I wait for my thread and keep the UI working?

Comment: For about the millionth time, don't wait for stuff in GUI event-hanler threads, ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never block the UI thread.

Typical pattern for background processing looks like follows:

1. Change UI to indicate that background processing is in progress (show progress bar, disable buttons, etc)
2. Start a background thread
3. In the background thread, after processing has finished, change the UI back and display processing results. Code that does it should be invoked using [`Platform.runLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) (as well as any other code that interacts with the UI from background threads)

Simplified example:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // 1
        setBackgroundProcessing(true); 

        // 2
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                doProcessing();

                // 3
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        displayResults();
                        setBackgroundProcessing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

The code above is not very elegant, you may want to use thread pools and/or `ListenableFuture`s to make it look better.