# Threads in JavaFX: do threads need to be killed?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm writing an application using JavaFX and my understanding is that, while the UI runs in a thread, all other non-UI operations must run in another. So far, all examples I've found are variations of the following:

```
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent a) {

        // Some UI operations

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                // Some non-UI operations

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        // Some operations to update the UI
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

My question is: do you need to somehow kill the thread in order to release its resources? In the examples I've never nobody seems to use Thread.join or any other similar method.

Also, would it be advisable to use setDaemon like this?

```
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent a) {

        // Some UI operations

        final Thread child = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                // Some non-UI operations

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        // Some operations to update the UI
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        child.setDaemon(true);
        child.start();

    }
});
```

Note:
According to this thread ([JavaFX multithreading - joining threads won't update the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578517/javafx-multithreading-joining-threads-wont-update-the-ui)) Thread.join must not be used, but it doesn't seem to address the question of what happens to the threads that are no longer needed or how to kill them.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing.  Please describe in a bit of detail what you are actually trying to do on these threads.

Comment: I guess the short answer is: "it's complicated".  It's hard to supply a definite catch-all answer for all possibilities.  There are a bunch of considerations which go into determining an appropriate thread management strategy.  For example, does code in the thread need to run like an atomic transaction to not leave stuff in an inconsistent state if shutdown?  Do threads run for entire length of app (so start on start and end on shutdown)?  Is the threaded code written to respond correctly to interrupts?  Is user based cancellation required?  Are the threads in a pool?  Using Executors?

Comment: It's not that complicated, actually. Essentially, the application takes some input from the users through textboxes, processes it and sends it to a server (that's the non-UI part). Then, the server response it's displayed on a TextArea in the user interface as it arrives (that's the Platform.runLater part). So the question is, how to handle the non-UI thread? Should it be explicitly killed or does Java releases the resources automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Threads will age out when there is nothing scheduled for them. However, it is not a good practice to depend on that, as it can take up resources.

The better approach is to use an `ExecutorService`, such as described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). A `ThreadPoolExecutor` can run one or more threads. You can use the same executor to keep submitting runnable tasks, and they will be executed on the threads that it manages. The documentation gives examples on how to shut down the executor service at the end of your application. If you are confident that you have no outstanding tasks being executed, you can issue `shutdownNow()` to immediately clean up all the threads.

Comment: "Threads will age out when there is nothing scheduled for them."  <== Can you describe what this means or link to some documentation that explains this process?  I've never heard of that before.

Comment: Sorry for the inexact terminology. In your example, you create a `Thread` object, referenced by the variable `child`. The `Runnable` you submit contains a reference to it when it is scheduled. When the `child` variable goes out of scope, and the runnable itself completes, the `Thread` object will be garbage collected. This happens eventually, and there are no guarantees when it does happen. Hence, my use of the loose term "age out".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had considered the ExecutorService option as well, but I finally chose the setDaemon approach (second example) as it required less changes on what I already had (first example). That said, would the setDaemon approach work well?

Comment: `setDaemon` is pretty much independent of using an executor service. You can use an executor service and configure it to use daemon threads if you want, or just use non-daemon threads (by default). Similarly you can create threads by hand (not using an executor service) and make them daemon threads or not.